# Python script fails with 'ImportError' when run from rc.local

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python-3

So I've tested that my script does attempt to run and I'm recording the error message of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/steamFriendStatus_v0.3.py", line 6, in <module>
       import telepot
ImportError: No module named 'telepot'
```

This module works fine running the script from terminal/IDLE/Thonny and I'm declaring to use Python 3 / full Python 3 directory in the rc.local command

My rc.local file is below:

```
exec > /tmp/rc-local.log 2>&1

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi


/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/steamFriendStatus_v0.3.py

exit 0
```

Comment: It might be the environment variables available to the script. If you run `export` from a regular shell and compare this with an `export` command in your `rc.local` (in the log file) you'll be able to see any difference, and you can fix this with `export VAR=...` in your rc.local file.

Comment: @EricClack by environment variable are you referring to the telepot module that it is saying it cannot find?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's worth noting that `rc.local` is [run by root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210941/184220), rather than the `pi` user which you are likely using at your terminal. It seems likely that your installation for the `telepot` module is installed only for the `pi` user, and hence when root runs the script, the module cannot be found. If this is the case, you have two options:

- **Install the `telepot` module globally for all users** with `sudo pip install telepot`, then leave your `rc.local` unchanged.
- **Switch to the `pi` user in rc.local** by replacing the old script line in`rc.local` with `sudo -H -u pi /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/steamFriendStatus_v0.3.py`.

Either of the above should ensure that the `telepot` module is available as required.

Comment: Thanks, 
the `sudo pip3 install telepot` did it! Now I have some errors with my script connecting to online APIs but I'll give it some googling first

Comment: Good to hear, @Purdy; you can mark this as accepted if you're happy with it — [that's our way of saying thanks here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you're still having trouble, feel free to link to your new question.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same problem with dill module.

If you already installed teleport as your pi user, and if `sudo pip` or `pip3 install` gives errors try:

```
sudo -H pip install teleport
```

this way, you can install it also for root, and it will start at rc.local